# Make multiple buttons highlight when touch begins

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton, touchesbegan

[image]

I have placed three buttons together in a view each of which will have a different profile image. I need all three buttons to highlight when touch begins on any individual one so that the three together appear to be one button. I have tried the following code but it does not work. Any ideas?

```
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(normalTap))
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    friendsBtn1.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    func normalTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        if sender.state == .began {
            friendsBtn2.isHighlighted = true
            friendsBtn3.isHighlighted = true
        }
        if sender.state == .ended {
            friendsBtn2.isHighlighted = false
            friendsBtn3.isHighlighted = false
        }
        print("Normal tap")
    }
```

Comment: have you set Highlighted image for friendsBtn2 and friendsBtn3?

Comment: checkout updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve the problem. Here is the code.

```
[friendsBtn1, friendsBtn2, friendsBtn3].forEach { button in
        button?.addTarget(self, action:#selector(highlightAllButtons(sender:)), for: .touchDown)
        button?.addTarget(self, action:#selector(unhighlightAllButtons(sender:)), for: [.touchUpInside, .touchUpOutside])
    }

func highlightAllButtons(sender: UIButton) {
    [friendsBtn1, friendsBtn2, friendsBtn3].forEach { button in
        button.isHighlighted = true
    }
}
func unhighlightAllButtons(sender: UIButton) {
    [friendsBtn1, friendsBtn2, friendsBtn3].forEach { button in
        button.isHighlighted = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think no need to `UITapGesture` you can manage like this way.
First you need to set highlighted image to the button And Setup button event as per bellow.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        friendsBtn2.setImage(UIImage(named: "highlighted.png"), for: .highlighted)
        friendsBtn3.setImage(UIImage(named: "highlighted.png"), for: .highlighted)

        friendsBtn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.touchDownEvent), for: .touchDown)
        friendsBtn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.touchUpInsideEvent), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
```

After that add  method `touchDownEvent()`,`touchUpInsideEvent()` in your ViewController.

```
func touchDownEvent() {
    self.allButtonHighlighted(fleg: true)
}

func touchUpInsideEvent() {
    self.allButtonHighlighted(fleg: false)
}

func allButtonHighlighted( fleg: Bool) {
    friendsBtn2.isHighlighted = fleg
    friendsBtn3.isHighlighted = fleg
}
```

I hope it will Works.

Comment: I am just using the regular highlighting of the button with Xcode 8.2.1 and not setting a highlighted image directly. I did try setting it as you said but the problem remains that my code is not setting the other buttons to be highlighted.

Comment: first use the breakpoints and check your code "friendsBtn2.isHighlighted = true" is execute or not ?

Answer (score -1):

Try `[button setSelected:YES];` for all the three buttons in your button action.